# PHP MySQL Insert Data

Tags: php, post, mysql

Im trying to insert data into a table in MySQL. I found/modified some code from w3Schools and still couldn't get it working. Heres what I have so far:

```
<?php
$rusername=$_POST['username']; 
$rname=$_POST['name'];
$remail=$_POST['emailadr'];
$rpassword=$_POST['pass'];
$rconfirmpassword=$_POST['cpass'];

if ($rpassword==$rconfirmpassword) {

    $con = mysql_connect("host","user","password");
    if (!$con)
     {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }
        mysql_select_db("mydbname ", $con);
    }

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (id, username, password)
    VALUES ('4', $rusername, $rpassword)");


?>
```

Did I mistype something? To my understanding "members" is the name of the table. If anyone knows whats wrong I appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you adding 4 as id? Just put `id` as auto-incrementing and you won't have to deal with it anymore. 

Also, id should be an integer, so no need of using quotes there

Comment: This is a SQL injection vulnerability. Please use parameterized queries (see PHP docs for PDO: http://php.net/pdo), or at the very least escape input with a function like `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: I just put 4 in to test it. Now it generates a random number. And yes, I have heard of SQL injection and I do use mysql_real_escape_string for the login. I haven't added it to the create account yet though.

Comment: this reminds me of: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query resulted from your code is:

```
INSERT INTO members (id, username, password) VALUES ('4', rusername, rpassword)
```

Note that in SQL string must be surrounded by `'`.

So update your code to this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (id, username, password)
             VALUES ('4', '$rusername', '$rpassword')");
```

Answer (score 0):

And your database name?

```
mysql_select_db("mydbname ", $con);
```

Even though it's called **mydbname** there's a weird space char in there..

You can also do

```
mysql_query("use mydbname", $con);
```

**EDIT**

Try to include the database connection flag in the query, and also replace '4' (that as nico said if it's an autoincrement key [id], it must be an integer, without quotes) by null:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO members VALUES
            (null, '$rusername', '$rpassword');", $con);
```